# How to generate syntax tree for a particular sentence like a+b*c where id->a|b|c?

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, automata-theory

Consider grammar : E-> E+E|E-E|E*E|E/E|(E)|id

I have tried at least 5 hours to solve this problem but failed. Please tell me,

- what is the idea to solve this problem?
- How to implement this?

Comment: Tnq @yuyoyuppe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax tree is built by parsing, which is in some sense applying the grammar in reverse. So you see that a, b, and c can only come from id which in turn can only come from E. Now you are at E+E*E. You can either reduce the E+E first or the E*E, then the other. The resulting E is the root of the tree. One of the two possible syntax trees (the one reducing first E*E) is this

```
  E
 /| \
E +   E
|    /|\
id  E * E
|   |   |
a   id  id
    |   |
    b   c
```

About the implementation, you would have to specifiy where and to what end you want to implement this.

Comment: How to implement this?

Comment: As I have said: you need to specify what exactly you want to implement in which language. What is the input (a string?), what should be the output (syntax tree is not a standard data structure), etc. Basically you have to construct a parser, read about this in any textbook about compilers.

Comment: C++   input : a+b*c

Comment: You are lucky in that your terminals are all just one symbol: a,b,c,+,*,-,/,(,). Further you have no operator precedence. So basically you can start from any side and the first three symbols will always let you apply a rule (after a->id) in reverse to shorten your string until you arrive at E. The only rule that needs some memory is the one with parentheses, because you have to remember how many are open. In this way you build the data structure that you desire.

Comment: Take the first three symbols from the right (to stick with the tree above): b*c; reduce to id * id and further to E * E and finally E; result: a+E; do  (again looking at the three rightmost symbols) a->id->E and E+E -> E. Of course, along the way you want to build a data structure that represents your syntax tree. What this should look like depends on your taste and what you want to use it for.

Comment: Is it possible to implement in C++? I worried with syntax tree. It is most difficult concept to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157651/discussion-between-peter-leupold-and-rashedcs).